# Django form won't render (modelForm)

Tags: django

I have an existing site, and I'm trying to render a form to it
I tried looping trough the form and rendering it field by field, but no luck. I think i might screwed up something in my views, im a beginner to django
HTML:

```
{%block wform%}
            <form method="POST" class="form">
                {% csrf_token %} 
                {{ form.as_p }}

                <div class="form__group">
                    {%if user.is_authenticated%}
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Your Data">
                    {%else%}
                    <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="submit">Submit Your Data</a>
                    {%endif%}
                    
                </div>
            </form>

            {%endblock wform%}
```

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from users.models import Profile

class WeightForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['weight','height','goal']
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from users import models
from users.models import Profile
from .forms import WeightForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Landing/index.html')

def formsave(request):
    form = WeightForm()
    return render(request, 'Landing/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
  from django.contrib import messages
  from users import models
  from users.models import Profile
  from .forms import WeightForm
  # Create your views here.
  def home(request):
   form = WeightForm()
   return render(request, 'Landing/index.html', {'form': form})
```